# Angular 6: Calling service observer.next from Http Interceptor causes infinite request loop

Tags: angular, jwt, angular6, angular-httpclient, angular-http-interceptors

I'm working on a website with authentication using JWT. I've created a HTTP interceptor class that adds the token to all requests headers and is used for catching 401 errors.

```js
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable, of} from 'rxjs';
import {JwtService} from '../service/jwt.service';
import {catchError} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {AlertService} from '../../shared/service/alert.service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {AlertType} from '../../shared/model/alert.model';

@Injectable()
export class HttpTokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private jwtService: JwtService, private alertService: AlertService, private router: Router) {
  }

  /**
   * Intercept HTTP requests and return a cloned version with added headers
   *
   * @param req incoming request
   * @param next observable next request
   */
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    // Add headers to all requests
    const headersConfig = {
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    };

    // Add token bearer to header when it's available
    const token = this.jwtService.getToken();
    if (token) {
      headersConfig['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
      headersConfig['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
    }

    const request = req.clone({setHeaders: headersConfig});

    // Return adjusted http request with added headers
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError((error: any) => {

        // Unauthorized response
        if (error.status === 401) {

          this.handleError();
          return of(error);
        }
        throw error;
      })
    );
  }

  /**
   * Handle http errors
   */
  private handleError() {

    // Destroy the token
    this.jwtService.destroyToken();

    // Redirect to login page
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);

    // This is causing infinite loops in HTTP requests
    this.alertService.showAlert({
      message: 'Your token is invalid, please login again.',
      type: AlertType.Warning
    });

  }

}
```

The class uses my JwtToken class to remove the token from the localstorage and redirect the user to the login page using the Angular Router. The showAlert method from the alertService is causing the http request to be repeated infinitely.

I think it's being caused by the Observer implementation in the alert service. But I've tried so many different implementations that I have really no idea what is going wrong.

```js
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Alert} from '../model/alert.model';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs';

/**
 * Alert Service: Used for showing alerts all over the website
 * Callable from all components
 */
@Injectable()
export class AlertService {

  public alertEvent: Subject<Alert>;

  /**
   * AlertService constructor
   */
  constructor() {
    this.alertEvent = new Subject<Alert>();
  }

  /**
   * Emit event containing an Alert object
   *
   * @param alert
   */
  public showAlert(alert: Alert) {
    this.alertEvent.next(alert);
  }
}
```

The alertService class is being used by an alert component that displays all the alert messages. This component is used in two main components: Dashboard & login.

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {AlertService} from '../../shared/service/alert.service';
import {Alert} from '../../shared/model/alert.model';

@Component({
  selector: '*brand*-alerts',
  templateUrl: './alerts.component.html',
})
export class AlertsComponent {

  // Keep list in global component
  public alerts: Array<Alert> = [];

  constructor(private alertService: AlertService) {

    // Hook to alertEvents and add to class list
    alertService.alertEvent.asObservable().subscribe(alerts => {
      // console.log(alerts);
      this.alerts.push(alerts);
    });
  }

}
```

In the following image is the issue clearly visible:

[video of loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HXnA.gif)

Kind regards.

**Edit: solved**

In the page that did a request there was a subscription initilialised on the alert service and that caused the http request to fire again. I simply have the alert component being the only subscriber to the alertService now and created a new service for the refresh. The answer from @incNick is indeed a correct implementation. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry of I'm busy on my job, but may my source make helpful.

```
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
...
return httpHandler.handle(request).pipe(
          tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
              if (event instanceof HttpResponse) { 
                  //this.loadingService.endLoading();
              }
          },
          (err: any) => {
              //this.loadingService.endLoading();
          }),
          catchError((err: any) => {
              if (err.status === 401) {
                  /*
                  this.modalController.create({
                      component: LoginComponent,
                      componentProps: {returnUrl: this.router.url},
                      showBackdrop: true
                  }).then(modal => modal.present());
                  */
              } else {
                  //this.messageService.showToast(`Some error happen, please try again. (Error-${err.status})`, 'error');
              }
              return throwError(err);
          })
      );
```

I'm return throwError(err) at end.

Comment: This does not seem to be the problem. I did delete the argument anyway since it wasn't used in the method itself. I've edited my OP

Comment: Hope it is ok :(

Comment: Unfortunately this does not make a difference. When the request fails with a 401 the user is still routed to the login page. But adding an alert using the alertService still causes the request to retry and send another alert.

Comment: I've tracked it down to the service class. Whenever the `this.alertEvent.next(alert);` action is called the request gets called again, fails and sends an alert again.

Comment: No worries, please only answer if you have the time for it. I'll look into it and come back to you!

Comment: See the OP for the answer, thanks for your help! I've marked your answer as accepted since it is a working implementation.